# XMLReader - parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 1

Tags: php

Читаю XML объектом класса XMLReader:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xml);
while ($reader->read()) {echo $reader->name;}
```

Все хорошо. Но некоторые xml-ы содержат символы из 4х байтной кодировки UTF8 и при парсинге выводится сообщение:

```
Warning: XMLReader::read(): /home/user1/web/input1.xml:19: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 1 in /home/user1/web/xmlloader.php on line 169
```

При этом чтение XML-файла прекращается.

Как игнорировать объектом XMLReader такие недопустимые символы и продолжать чтение с текущей позиции пусть даже с потерей узла?

Возможно ли предварительно установить для объекта кодировку utf8mb4?

Comment: ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Для файлов xml, которые я использовал, мне сначала пришлось удалить все недопустимые символы, чтобы избежать ошибок недопустимого символа PCDATA. Если это кому-то поможет, вот скрипт, который я использовал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72244297/fastest-most-efficient-way-to-check-for-changes-in-a-large-xml-file-100k-entr#:~:text=note%3A%20for%20the%20xml%20files%20i%20used%2C

Comment: да, видел это. Но хотелось бы парсить без замены.